# JUnit5 Gradle plugin the filename or extension is too long

Tags: java, windows, gradle, junit, junit5

After adding `org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin` into the build and migrating everything from junit4 Gradle started to break with below error.

All runs fine with the vintage runner but junit5 tests are not.

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':server:junitPlatformTest'.

Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe''
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
```

**Do I need to configure the junit5 test consumer somehow to deal with this sort of things? or maybe there is some uber jar handling those?**

---

**EDIT1**

I have a suspicion this might be the classpath, im going to generate an uberjar with all junit modules.

---

**EDIT2**

Looking into the source code seems like Junit plugin adds loads to the classpath

```
// Note: the user's test runtime classpath must come first; otherwise, code
// instrumented by Clover in JUnit's build will be shadowed by JARs pulled in
// via the junitPlatform configuration... leading to zero code coverage for
// the respective modules.
classpath = project.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath + project.configurations.junitPlatform
```

Im curious if I could wipe out this configuration `junitPlatform` after the project evaluate as all JUnit dependencies are added anyway for the code to compile, then the plugin is just adding loads on the top. And I created a project that wraps all Junit5 libs inside one artefact.

---

**EDIT3**

I did manage to pack up all jupiter artefacts into 1 to shrink the cp a little, but still my classpath goes over 35k which is a bit weird

**How does gradle run junit5 tests then?** seems like it puts all transitives from all other projects related, and adds them the cp, which then brakes with error=206

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GRADLE 4.6 SUPPORTS JUNIT 5!**
Remember that vintage engine need to be same version as the jupiter now
Edited: 16/03/2018

---

I have managed to make it all working with below code.

it is going to produce a jar with a manifest and put that jar on the classpath.

It's not using any plugins just running the platform as a javaExec task.

This file needs to be applied to the project you want to run your test on.

```
def version = "5.0.1"
def platformVersion = "1.0.1"
def vintageVersion = "4.12.1"
def projectCp = "${project.name}Classpath.jar"

dependencies {

    compile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$version"
    compile "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:$platformVersion"
    compile "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:$platformVersion"

    testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"

    testCompile "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:$version"

    testRuntime "org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:$vintageVersion"
    testRuntime "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console:$platformVersion"
    testRuntime "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$version"
}

afterEvaluate {
    if (!project.tasks.findByName('packClasspath')) {
        task packClasspath(type: Jar) {
            archiveName = projectCp
            version = ''
            manifest {
                attributes 'Class-Path':
                project.configurations.testRuntime.collect { "file:///${it.absolutePath}" }.join(' ')}

            }
        }

        if (!project.tasks.findByName('jupiterTest')) {
            task jupiterTest(type: JavaExec) {
                jvmArgs '-ea'
                classpath = files(
                    "${project.buildDir}\\libs\\${projectCp}",
                    project.sourceSets.test.output,
                    project.sourceSets.main.output,
                )

                main 'org.junit.platform.console.ConsoleLauncher'
                args '--scan-class-path'
                args "--reports-dir=$project.testReportDir"
            }
        }

        test.dependsOn jupiterTest
        jupiterTest.dependsOn packClasspath
        jupiterTest.dependsOn testClasses

        test.enabled = false

}
```

Alternatively, now you can use this plugin which does the above, just apply it to the project with too long classpath.

https://github.com/viswaramamoorthy/gradle-util-plugins

Edit

**GRADLE 4.6 SUPPORTS JUNIT 5!**